# Which is better for readability?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c, coding-style

Which is better style in terms of readability?

```
 bool isNew = (SelectList.Key > 0) ? true: false;
```

or

```
 bool isNew = SelectList.Key > 0;
```

I know it is very trivial, but just wanted to get it better... Thanks

EDIT : swapped the values in conditional statement

Comment: They aren't even equivalent...

Comment: I think you've just proved that the second is better. The first reminds me of beginner code like this `if (something == true)`.

Comment: Is this even a question?

Comment: its not about proving expertise :), Just wanted to know which is good for readability

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian My point is that the second is more readable. With the first you have to double check which way round `false` and `true` are.

Comment: Well its obviously the second one, which also has better performance. Why doing an *inline if* that returns true for true and false for false? The bool result you want is implicit in the condition itself.

Comment: @Havenard It would be a poor compiler indeed that didn't produce that same machine code from both examples.

Comment: Maybe, but why push it? The redundancy is just ugly to tell the least.

Comment: @Havenard How do you know which has better performance? And optimization should not be the key here as I doubt that many people can write code where the issue above would be the performance bottleneck (if there is a difference, which I do not know)

Comment: Nobody said anything about bottlenecks, but you don't have to be Einstein to know that performing two operations is most coastly than doing one.

Comment: Well, the issue is just the readability here, of course. and about the COST, many processors, may be all of them have this COMPARE built into their ISA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say this is better

`bool isNew = SelectList.Key > 0;`

or you can enhance readability, in my point of view by writing like this

```
//set the value of isNew to true if bla bla else false.
bool isNew = (SelectList.Key > 0);
```

the latter would force me to process the expression first instead of getting impression that you are assigning `SelectList.Key` to `isNew`.

Comment: Good point. Eye recognizes condition faster may be because it's more common to see conditions in parentheses like in `if` and `while`

Comment: For some of us, redundant parentheses reduce readability because we have to figure out what their purpose is, and eventually recognize that they aren't doing anything.